# How to retrieve SAML SP Metadata from Spring Security 5

Tags: spring-security, saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am using [SAML feature set in Spring Security Core 5](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#saml2) (not [Spring Security SAML extension](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-saml), which is obsolete). So far I can bring up the [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/d8aa208a9f8b1db8fa3265845cbb6d4b1f5b6445/samples/boot/saml2login) and login to [IdP](https://simplesaml-for-spring-saml.cfapps.io/) without issue, even it is in my localhost. However, I would like to extract my SP metadata to provide to my IdP. When I access the SP metadata URL (`http://localhost:8080/saml2/service-provider-metadata/simplesamlphp`), the sample redirected me to the IdP login page. Seems all paths are protected. I customized with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, but when I accessed SP metadata URL, it returned 404.

What is the correct SP metadata URL? How to retrieve it?

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/saml2/service-provider-metadata/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .saml2Login();
        
    }
}
```

***Update on 26 Jun 2020***

The code search result of `SPSSODescriptor` is empty in [Spring Security Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/search?q=SPSSODescriptor&unscoped_q=SPSSODescriptor), but not in [Spring Security SAML extension Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/search?q=SPSSODescriptor&unscoped_q=SPSSODescriptor). Is it there is new way to setup SAML SP without metadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because Spring Security team still have not implemented the SAML 2.0 SP Metadata Endpoint in Spring Security v5.3 and below. See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8693) and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8685) for details.

**Update:**
It has been implemented after [6 Aug 2020](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/b999faa5a0d7314b82421719886a01e31595628d#diff-81a8047cc4069e0ae01dcb90c3e43e2c829bd24006e7f3df32f72310917b4eb8)